# Jupyter widgets clear_output() does not work

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I was using the ipywidgets dropdown to create plots for the columns listed in the dropdown. I have two issues. Would any one help?

1. I used the clear_ouput() to clear out the graph before the next selection. But it did not work;
2. When I first time clicked the first item in the dropdown list ("quarter"), it did not response (No graph showed). I have to select other items first before I can generate the graph for "quarter".

Thanks a lot!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as ipw

url = "https://data.london.gov.uk/download/number-international-visitors-london/b1e0f953-4c8a-4b45-95f5-e0d143d5641e/international-visitors-london-raw.csv"
df_london = pd.read_csv(url)

dropdown_Col = ipw.Dropdown(options = ['quarter', 'market', 'dur_stay', 'mode'], description='Sel Col NM:')

output = ipw.Output()

def Col_Sel(ColNm):
    output.clear_output()

    with output:
        sns.set_style("whitegrid")
        sns.relplot(x=ColNm, y='visits', data=df_london, kind='line', ci=None) 

def dropdown_Col_eventhandler(change):
    Col_Sel(change.new)    

dropdown_Col.observe(dropdown_Col_eventhandler, names='value')

display(dropdown_Col)
display(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added plt.show() and now The clear_output works.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as ipw

url = "https://data.london.gov.uk/download/number-international-visitors-london/b1e0f953-4c8a-4b45-95f5-e0d143d5641e/international-visitors-london-raw.csv"
df_london = pd.read_csv(url)

dropdown_Col = ipw.Dropdown(options = ['quarter', 'market', 'dur_stay', 'mode'], description='Sel Col NM:')

output = ipw.Output()

def Col_Sel(ColNm):
    output.clear_output()

    with output:
        sns.set_style("whitegrid")
        sns.relplot(x=ColNm, y='visits', data=df_london, kind='line', ci=None)


def dropdown_Col_eventhandler(change):
    Col_Sel(change.new)    

dropdown_Col.observe(dropdown_Col_eventhandler, names='value')

display(dropdown_Col)
display(output)
```